# MySQL convert date string to Unix timestamp

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp

How do I convert the following format to unix timestamp?

```
Apr 15 2012 12:00AM
```

The format I get from DB seems to have `AM` at the end. 
I've tried using the following but it did not work:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, Sales.SalesDate, 103) AS DTSALESDATE,  
CONVERT(TIMESTAMP, Sales.SalesDate, 103) AS TSSALESDATE

where Sales.SalesDate value is Apr 15 2012 12:00AM
```

Comment: Is the date stored as text in the DB ?

Comment: Is it really a MySQL question? Your [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) doesn't suggest so.

Comment: Seems what the question is about MSSQL.

Answer (score 261, accepted):

Here's an example of how to **convert `DATETIME` to UNIX timestamp**:
`SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('Apr 15 2012 12:00AM', '%M %d %Y %h:%i%p'))`

Here's an example of how to **change date format**:
`SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('Apr 15 2012 12:00AM', '%M %d %Y %h:%i%p')),'%m-%d-%Y %h:%i:%p')`

**Documentation:** [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp), [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Comment: Thanks .This works.This can also be used in other statements such as update,delete,insert etc

Comment: After so many trials your solution worked for me: ```select * from (SELECT order_increment_id, FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(order_date, '%d %M  %Y %h:%i:%s %p')),'%Y-%m-%d') as order_date, email_sent FROM `packingslip_header`
 where email_sent=0) t
 where order_date >= '2019-11-13'
 ORDER BY order_increment_id ASC``` This is the date I had ```31 Oct 2017 4:16:49 pm``` so I needed to use ```%d %M  %Y %h:%i:%s %p``` for ```STR_TO_DATE```

Answer (score 38):

You will certainly have to use both [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert your date to a MySQL standard date format, and  [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) to get the timestamp from it.

Given the format of your date, something like

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(Sales.SalesDate, '%M %e %Y %h:%i%p'))
```

Will gives you a valid timestamp. Look the [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) documentation to have more information on the format string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a timestamp as returned by java's `Date.getTime()` you should multiply by 1000.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('Apr 15 2012 12:00AM', '%M %d %Y %h:%i%p'))*1000
```

Now for a more standard date format use:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('2022-12-14 20:58:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))*1000
```

Answer (score -5):

From http://www.epochconverter.com/

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01 00:00:00', GETUTCDATE())

My bad, SELECT unix_timestamp(time) Time format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS or YYMMDD or YYYYMMDD. More on using timestamps with MySQL:

http://www.epochconverter.com/programming/mysql-from-unixtime.php
```

Comment: This answer is for MSSQL (although this question has some confusion).