# Comparing timestamp to current time from database

Tags: php

I need to test current time against a datetime from database, if it has been 30 mins then execute code, if not then dont. This is where I am at and I am stuck:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("hostname", "username", "password", "database");
$q = "SELECT id FROM dwCache ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$qu = mysqli_query($link, $q);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($qu, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $cache = $row['cache'];
        $timest = $row['time'];
    }

$newTime = 
$difference = $timest
if($timest >= )
```

As you can see towards the bottom I lose it as I am not sure what to do.

`$timest` returns : `2013-02-01 12:36:01` as the format `Y-m-d` `h-i-s`

Apologies on double post, other deleted.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

First convert `$timest` to timestamp

```
$time = strtotime($timest);

$curtime = time();

if(($curtime-$time) > 1800) {     //1800 seconds
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Is the 1800 seconds, mins or hours?

Comment: seconds but all this multiple converting of dates is a waste of time/resources when you can do it all in query and just get back a list of ID's you need to process.

Answer (score 13):

do it all in sql statement

```
SELECT id FROM `dqCache` WHERE `time`<DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE);
```

This will return everything from your table where the time column is before 30 minutes before now.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use [unix timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) in this situation.

```
$timest = date('u'); // gets the unix timestamp
$q = "SELECT id 
      FROM `dwCache` 
      WHERE {$timest} - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`timestamp_col`) > 1800";
```

**Explanation:**

This basically calculates the difference between the current time and the time in the table column. If it's higher than 1800 (30 minutes), it will select the row, and your PHP code will be executed.

**Advantages**

There are some advantages to using this instead of the PHP check you started doing. You will select fewer rows, thus occupy less memory.

**PS:**

Thumbs up for using `MySQLi` !

Comment: FYI: You should **not use** this approach **in 2020** for SQL injection reasons.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT id FROM dwCache ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

you'll get only `id` field, it's the first.
The second, for time converting: [MySQL convert datetime to Unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133760/mysql-convert-datetime-to-unix-time-stamp)

Third: you can convert your time string using `strtotime` function.