# Comparing Current Time To Timestamp In Mysql DB With PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting values from the FB API into my DB. One of those values is a `timestamp` for each one of the events creation time.

The way it is set up right now its grabbing all of the users `tagged_places`. I am trying to compare the time the `tagged_place` was created to the Current Time and if its not within the past 24 hours I want it to be ignored.

I know I need to convert the timestamp in the DB for a way for php to read it. I find this

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647338/comparing-timestamp-to-current-time-from-database)

But I am not understanding how to implement it.

Here is my insert query to the DB,

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('
    INSERT INTO taggedPlaces
    (id, created_time, place_id, latitude, longitude, name)
    VALUES
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
');

foreach($graphObject['tagged_places']->data as $data) {
   $stmt->execute(array(
       $data->id,
       $data->created_time,
       $data->place->id,
       $data->place->location->latitude,
       $data->place->location->longitude,
       $data->place->name
   ));
}
```

How can I change this to only insert the values in data that have been created in the past 24 hours?

Comment: Is `$data->created_time` a timestamp or a datetime?

Comment: What is your schema? At least provide a representative sample of `created_time`?

Comment: Convert both time values to Unix timestamps, then compare?

Comment: Im sorry if im noy beung clear. U havw never deal with this before. I said timestamp in my question what else would you need to know? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `$data->created_time` is a `datetime` or similar format:

```
foreach($graphObject['tagged_places']->data as $data) {
   
   if (time() - strtotime($data->create_time) < 86400) { ...

       $stmt->execute(array(
           $data->id,
           $data->created_time,
           $data->place->id,
           $data->place->location->latitude,
           $data->place->location->longitude,
           $data->place->name
       ));
   }
}
```

If `$data->created_time` is already a timestamp, then `strtotime()` is not necessary:

```
if (time() - $data->created_time < 86400) { ...
```

---

Some explanation:

- A [Unix Timestamp](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/) is the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970.
- [time()](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.time.php) returns the current unix timestamp.
- [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) converts a string to a unix timestamp.
- `time() - strtotime($data->created_time)` is the difference in seconds between
  the current time and the time stored.
- `86400` is the number of seconds in 24 hours.

So the statement

```
if (time() - strtotime($data->created_time) < 86400) { ...
```

says:

**If the difference, in seconds, between the current date/time and the date/time of the tagged place is less than 24 hours (86400 seconds), proceed with insert.**

Comment: Hey thanks for that, would you mind explaining what `if (time() - $data->created_time < 86400) {` is exactly?

Comment: Thanks so much that worked perfectly. Just for someone else that comes across this I did have to convert it. Thank you for adding that in your answer. If you don't mind I would appreciate you explaining the 86400 but thanks again.