# Time diference between now and mysql datetime

Tags: php, mysql, date

i've got little problem here. I recieve reg_time from database in this format: Y-m-d H:i:s (2020-08-26 13:50:11)
and i want to compare it with current time: $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
Is there any function for it? THX

Comment: You can ask the DB to deliver for instance `SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, datefield, NOW() AS diffMinutes`. See [Timestampdiff](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timestampdiff-function.php).

Comment: You can use [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert these to unix timestamps (seconds) and then can just subtract to get the difference. And `/ 60` to convert to minutes, etc. `$diff = strtotime("2020-08-26 13:50:11") - time();`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing timestamp to current time from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647338/comparing-timestamp-to-current-time-from-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) classes are intended for this:

```
<?php
$timeInput = '2020-08-26 13:50:11';

$origin = new DateTime($timeInput);
$target = new DateTime();

$interval = $origin->diff($target);

echo $interval->format('Registered %y years, %m months, %d days, %h hours, %i minutes, %s seconds ago').PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: you are my savior

Comment: btw, can i do something like 
if ($interval->format(%m)==0)? can i operate it somehow

Comment: Yes, if you just use a single format field like that it will just return a number that you can operate on. Just be sure you understand what DateInterval returns - if the interval has 35 days, you would get something like  1 month, 5 days, not the total number of days.

Answer (score 1):

There's a package called [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon), it's very useful for date manipulation. For your use case looks like it could be solved using a method called `diffForHumans()`

So, the full example would be:

```
Carbon::parse('2020-08-26 13:50:11')->diffForHumans();
```

The output would be `1 day ago`

Edit:

The question was fully rewritten