# How can I convert a column of date strings in a mysql db to UNIX timestamps?

Tags: php, mysql

I had my query wrong for the first fifty or so entries of a database table and because of this my date field has entries like "January 5th, 2013".

Can someone help me out with a query that will take all the entries in the date field and simply convert them to unix timestamps?

Researched lots of other questions here but nothing I have found seems to address manipulating/converting a group of dates after the fact.

Thanks

Comment: have you taken the **date** filed as **varchar**?

Comment: did you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133760/mysql-convert-datetime-to-unix-time-stamp)

Comment: yeah I did unfortunately...can I change the structure then run a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select all rows and use `strtotime` for getting timestamp value and then update the rows.

Comment: yep...great....just need some help getting out of my one dimensional head when working with this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using php, use "strtotime()" function and update the values in data base.

Comment: that is a great and simple suggestion...I often forget that I can easily manipulate the database just by making a quick script also..thanks. "foreach date..convert that to strtotime and update!"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2007-11-30 10:30:19');
```

read more here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

Answer (score 0):

PHP;

```
$ts = strtotime("January 5th, 2013");
echo date("Y-m-d", $ts); // 2013-01-05
```

SQL;

```
UPDATE `table` SET `date_field` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date_field`);
```

And, if you want to change column type (I prefer `INT` type for performance issues);

```
ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY `date_field` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
```

But after this, you need to insert all data to this column as integer, so;

```
$time = time(); // or $time = strtotime("January 5th, 2013");
INSERT INTO `table` (`date_field`) VALUES ($time)
```