# How to convert a timestamp to a string

Tags: mysql, timestamp

This is a bit weird. I need to save a timestamp into a varchar(15), the column is defined as varchar(15) and it stores the actual numeric timestamp.

So I have something like "2015-03-01 20:00:00" and it need to be saved as "1427725068". Is there any way to do so directly in mysql? Thanks

Comment: UNIX_TIMESTAMP()  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-time

Comment: This is what you're probably looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133760/mysql-convert-datetime-to-unix-timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The varchar dates are not real date and you need to convert them to real date before doing any further operation. The function is `str_to_date` and then use `unix_timestamp` on it to get the value as

```
mysql> select unix_timestamp(str_to_date('2015-03-01 20:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) as utime;
+------------+
| utime      |
+------------+
| 1425220200 |
+------------+
```

Comment: Should work, but if you try to do insert into table (field_varchar_15) values mysql> select unix_timestamp(str_to_date('2015-03-01 20:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) as utime; it doesn't store the real timestamp but the date converted to 2015- .....

Comment: I did not get could you explain a bit ?

Comment: sorry, missunderstanding :) you're right, that works

Answer (score 0):

Here is fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd7f40/1

```
create table table1 (id int, timestamp_varchar varchar(15));

insert into table1 values(1,UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-03-01 20:00:00'));

select * from table1;
```

output:

```
1, 1425258000
```