# How to update / convert YYYY-MM-DD date to timestamp in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, timestamp

I found very similar questions like [MySQL convert datetime to Unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133760/mysql-convert-datetime-to-unix-timestamp) , [How to convert DATETIME to TIMESTAMP in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37881542/how-to-convert-datetime-to-timestamp-in-mysql) related to this question. But I don't know how to apply those answers to my question...

I have a column (varchar type and  I can't change the datatype to date because of some technical limitation of CMS I used) called "start_date" in Students table. Dates are displayed as `YYYY-MM-DD`. I want to change them as timestamp .

I am looking something like,

```
UPDATE students SET start_date= convert_this_to_timestamp (start_date);
```

So basically I need to convert something like `2012-12-30` to `1356843600` using MySQL.

Comment: Come on. If you're capable of formulating the question, you're surely capable of answering it.

Comment: Create a new numeric column and set it.  Don't store your dates as text, and don't continue doing this by storing the UNIX timestamp values into the same column.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Actually this is for a WordPress site.. I use columns name table names as just an example... I can't change any column type or anything since thats how WordPress comes... But to write understandble question I use an example... But i want to run this query on WordPress wp_postmeta table since Date is saved as custom fild... But I need to convert them to timestamp...

Comment: Please try this? `UPDATE students SET start_date_timestamp= UNIX_TIMESTAMP (start_date) LIMIT 1;`   If it works for the one row as expected, remove the limit and run for the rest of the records. Create a new field `start_date_timestamp` with `integer` type for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @Tim Biegeleisen said, you need to add a new  numeric column:

```
UPDATE students SET start_date_ts = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d'));
```