# How to update a unixtime column based on a Timestamp column?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, unix-timestamp

In MariaDB 10, I want to fill `slug` column with unixtime based on `created_at` column, which is formatted like `2017-09-07 02:39:18`

Here is the query that I came up with based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11133965/5774375) answer:

```
UPDATE joke SET slug = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(created_at, '%Y %m %d  %h:%i:%s'));
```

But the result is `0` for all column. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `STR_TO_DATE` part you don't need string to date conversion if you already have a date object stored in your created_at column

```
UPDATE joke SET slug = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at);
```

[UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)